# Create a subclass of dict and Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclassing

For a web application I want to have a raise-able `dict`.

```
from json import dumps

class RaiseableDict(dict, Exception): pass  # This won't work.

# I want this to work without change:

try:
    raise RaiseableDict(message='Some message text.')
except RaiseableDict as rd:
    rd['key'] = 'value'
    rd.update({'error_code': 42})
    dumps(rd)
```

How can I avoid

```
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

and have some raise-able `dict`-like exception that can directly be JSON-dumped without having to access a special attribute of the exception subclass or having to use `json.dumps`'s `default=` argument?

Comment: Have you considered implementing the [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) abstract base class?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. The resulting instances won't be JSON-serializable.

Comment: Oh interesting, I see from e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14631898/3001761 that only actual `dict` subclasses get serialised, not any `Mapping`. You might be SOL, then; those types don't cooperate at the C level :/

Comment: Yep, [the `json` module requires `dict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/json/encoder.py#L430), and `raise` requires `BaseException`, and these just cannot mix.

Comment: What's wrong with using `json.dumps`'s `default` parameter though?

Comment: It's often said that one should "prefer composition to inheritance". Is there any reason your custom exception has to *be* a `dict` rather than *have* a `dict` as an additional attribute? `dumps({'exception': rd, 'key': 'value', 'error_code': 42})` does not seem unreasonable, either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply define the methods that you need for the exception to work as a dictionary and also define a dumps method of your exception?

```
>>> import json
>>> class RaiseableDict(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        self._dict = {}
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dict[key] = value
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]
    def update(self, other_dict):
        self._dict.update(other_dict)
    def dumps(self):
        return json.dumps(self._dict)


>>> try:
    raise RaiseableDict(message='Some message text.')
except RaiseableDict as rd:
    rd['key'] = 'value'
    rd.update({'error_code': 42})
    rd.dumps()


'{"key": "value", "error_code": 42}'
```